# Parsing XML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parsing, xml-parsing

I am using ajax in my jsp page to get all the values from the server.

I am sending it from the server to a jsp page forwarding as XML dataType.

Here is the JSP code (which contains XML):

```
<a>
 <olah>${query}</alh>
 <pp>
    <c:forEach var="pName" items="${names}">
       <z>${pName}</z>
    </c:forEach>
 </pp>
</a>
```

Now in the ajax response i want to get these values using jquery like so:

```
     success: function(resultData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //here parsing the xml data and get all results.  
      }
```

How can I parse the XML data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML.com has a [great tutorial](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2007/10/10/jquery-and-xml.html) on how to parse XML with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass

```
dataType: 'xml'
```

as one of the parameters of the AJAX call. This way, `resultData` should be a XML object and you won't need to parse it.